# Why am I getting a 'Page Not Found' error in Django's URL patterns?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm just trying to create a small application to output 'Hello World'. When I run my code, it says 'Page not found' and gives me the following reason:

> 'Using the URLconf defined in helloworld_project.urls, Django tried
>   these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/
>
> home/
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.'

I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening. I've included a few samples of my code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from my_app.views import HomeView
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', HomeView.as_view())
]
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Home Page</title></head>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Django in the port for example 8000, the url:

```
localhost:8000/
```

is the empty pattern url.

according to your URLs definitions you've to:

```
localhost:8000/home/
```

or change your url to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('^$', HomeView.as_view())    # Point the empty pattern to your view.
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your url like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', someview), 
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls) ),
    path('home/', HomeView.as_view(), name='somename')
]
```

The error is obtained because when you run your project, it looks for an empty url like `localhost:8000/` instead of `localhost:8000/home/`.